# How to get rid of all number below the 3rd decimal place?

Tags: javascript

For example I have this number 1.111111, and I just want it to be 1.11, how do I get rid of the extra 1's?

```
var number = 1.111111;
```

Comment: I suppose it's too obvious to do this: `var number = 1.11;`

Comment: What about rounding? What do you want if the number is `1.116111;`? `1.11` or `1.12`? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: have you tried with tofixed() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript **casting a string to number** `+number` because after

`toFixed` `var number` become a string.

```js
var number = 1.111111.toFixed(2);
var newNumber = +number;
console.log(newNumber)
console.log(typeof newNumber)
```

Use  `toFixed`

**example :**

```
var number = 1.111111.toFixed(2);
var newNumber = +number;
```

Comment: That convert to a string tough.

Comment: thanks i update my answer

Comment: So use parseFloat or typeof?

Comment: parseFloat i just used typeof to show you that it become a string after a toFixed

Comment: or you can just use + instead of parseFloat